# passing variables to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Hi can someone please tell me why this code  is incorrect?  I'm trying to pass two variable values to a function.

```
$( "#resizable-text1, #resizable-text2" ).draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper1",
    scroll: false, 
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-idSuffix');
        adjust_pos($('#resizable-text',id));
    }
});

function adjust_pos(elem, id) {
    alert('elem = '+elem)
    alert('id = '+id)
    var currentPos = $("#"+elem+id).position()
    var xpos = parseInt(currentPos.left)
    var ypos = parseInt(currentPos.top)

    then use variables ele and id...
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `$(this).attr("data-idSuffix")` use `$(this).data('idSuffix')` as jQuery (since version 1.5 or so) understands "data-" attributes already.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll adjust the idsuffix issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the string in the jQuery `$()` function, because in your function you will do that anyways (`$("#"+elem+id).position()`). Simply send the string.

So this should work:

```
adjust_pos('#resizable-text', id);
```

**EDIT:** Also, either in your function `adjust_pos` or in the parameter you pass you should remove a `#` because otherwise there would be two. I recommend you remove in the function, so if for some reason you want to send a class selector, you can do that too.

```
var currentPos = $(elem+id).position();
```

Comment: +1 The function requires a string instead of a jQuery object, though the function is also concatenating the `#`, so it needs to be removed on one end or the other.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks, I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According your code of `adjust_pos` function, it is like to be `adjust_pos('resizable-text', id);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your second closing bracket is in the wrong place:

```
adjust_pos($('#resizable-text'),id);
```

**Update**

As has been pointed out in the comments, you don't actually need to pass in the jQuery object given what your function does with the parameter. You simply need to pass in the id of the element as a string.

Given your current code you can do:

```
adjust_pos('resizable-text',id);
```

or with the adjustment to your code that japrescott recomended (removing the hash from the function and passing it in as part of the parameter):

```
adjust_pos('#resizable-text',id);
```

Comment: Thanks to all that answered.  Yes I am that stupid, it wokrs now!

Comment: If you look at the function, this won't work. It expects a string, not a jQuery wrapped object.

Answer (score 0):

this line;

```
 adjust_pos($('#resizable-text',id));
```

must be like this;

```
 adjust_pos($('#resizable-text'),id);
```

Comment: If you look at the function, this won't work. It expects a string, not a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: yeah, your solution is correct. I saw this little mistake and didn't continue to analyze the code.